# Can I put 'which' in place of 'where' in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, transitivity

The following passage is the excerpt from a school textbook. What I want to know is whether 'where' in the passage can be replaced with 'which.'

I know the verb 'hit' can be used both as transitive verb and as intransitive verb.

In this context, can I put 'which' in place of 'where' and use 'hit' as transitive? I think it makes no difference.

> Here is a story of a young man who survived Hurricane Sandy, one of
>   the most violent storms ever to hit the United States. A lady named
>   Christine at Toms River, New Jersey, **where** the hurricane hit hard,
>   was lucky enough to escape from her house before the storm hit. When
>   she returned to her damaged house, after the storm had passed, she
>   found a note.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct. You can use 'which' instead of 'where' and make the verb 'hit' transitive. It won't change the meaning of the sentence.